# Select with multiple conditions

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In form user need to check options who will receive newsletter, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="male"  value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="female"  value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="person" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="company" value="1" />
```

But I have problem how to create query for db with checked options

I have this code so far, but it is not good, because newsletter need to be 1 all the time and after that I have OR, because when I put AND I don't get the results that I need:

```
if($options['male']) {
            $sqlAddMale = " OR gender = 2 ";
        }
        if($options['female']) {
            $sqlAddFemale = " OR gender = 1 ";
        }
        if($options['person']) {
            $sqlAddPerson = " OR VAT = '' ";
        }
        if($options['company']) {
            $sqlAddCompany = " OR VAT <> '' ";
        }

        $query = "
            SELECT email FROM users WHERE newsletter=1
            ".$sqlAddMale."
            ".$sqlAddFemale."
            ".$sqlAddPerson."
            ".$sqlAddCompany."          
            ";
```

Comment: Start with your SQL query first in SQL and get that to work, all the OR's makes the results very open, Post your SQL that should work for one example for instance (something you would expect)

Comment: if you don't get the results you want - is there something wrong with the data? at a glance you should be using `AND`

Comment: @Goikiu when i check for example female and VAT i dont get results that i want, because query look like this `SELECT acEmail AS email FROM _site_vuser WHERE anNewsletter=1 OR anGender = 1 OR acVAT = ""` and it should look like this `SELECT acEmail AS email FROM _site_vuser WHERE anNewsletter=1 AND anGender = 1 OR acVAT = ''`

Comment: @gandrap i added an answer for you here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30774504/4323504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need something like this:

```
$placeOr = false;
if($options['male']) {
    $placeOr = true;
    $sqlAddMale = " (newsletter=1 AND gender = 2) ";
}
if($options['female']) {
    $sqlAddFemale = (($placeOr)?" Or ":"");
    $sqlAddFemale .= " (newsletter=1 AND gender = 1) ";
    $placeOr = true;
}
if($options['person']) {
    $sqlAddPerson = (($placeOr)?" Or ":"");
    $sqlAddPerson .= " (newsletter=1 AND VAT = '') ";
    $placeOr = true;
}
if($options['company']) {
    $sqlAddCompany = (($placeOr)?" Or ":"");
    $sqlAddCompany .= " (newsletter=1 AND VAT <> '') ";
    $placeOr = true;
}

$query = "
    SELECT email FROM users WHERE 
    ".$sqlAddMale."
    ".$sqlAddFemale."
    ".$sqlAddPerson."
    ".$sqlAddCompany."          
    ";
```

Comment: i have error then in sql, here is query after your code when i check female and person  `SELECT acEmail AS email FROM _site_vuser WHERE (newsletter=1 AND anGender = 1) (newsletter=1 AND acVAT = '')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve your issue, use one variable to build up your where clause, use `AND` operater when you are adding the first condition, else use `OR`

```
$sqlString = '';
if($options['male']) {
         $sqlString = " AND gender = 2 ";
    }
    if($options['female']) {
        if(!$sqlString) $sqlString = " AND gender = 1 ";
        else
            $sqlString .= " OR gender = 1 ";
    }
    if($options['person']) {
        if(!$sqlString) $sqlString = " AND VAT = '' ";
        else
            $sqlString .= " OR VAT = '' ";
    }
    if($options['company']) {
        if(!$sqlString) $sqlString = " AND VAT <> '' ";
        else 
           $sqlString .= " OR VAT <> '' ";
    }

    $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE newsletter=1'".$sqlString."'";
```

Comment: @gandrap  i made a mistake on the 1st condition, so now i edited it, instead of `$sqlString = " OR gender = 2 ";` I now have `$sqlString = " AND gender = 2 "`;